# Changing a `docker` example script to run on a local file (R package)

Tags: r, docker, cran

[This](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2015/01/18/) blog post contains a **very** cool script to run `CRAN` tests on `R` package inside a `docker` container. For example this script runs the CRAN check on the `RcppAnnoy` package:

```
docker run --rm -ti -v $(pwd):/mnt rocker/r-devel-ubsan-clang check.r --setwd /mnt --install-deps RcppAnnoy_0.0.6.tar.gz
```

My question is simple: in this example, the tested package (`RcppAnnoy_0.0.6.tar.gz`) can be substituted by any package that can be downloaded from `CRAN`. How should I change the script to substitute `RcppAnnoy_0.0.6.tar.gz` by a `R` package found on my  computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I change the script to substitute `RcppAnnoy_0.0.6.tar.gz` by a R package found on my computer?

Simply copy your R package in your current directory, since the [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/) command will mount `pwd` (where your package would be) to `/mnt`, and the [`check.r` command](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/examples/check.r) will set the wd (working directory) to the same `/mnt`.

Comment: Thanks, you changed my Sunday for the better!